# Applescript to change Mac display resolution to "Scaled", "Larger text"

Tags: macos, applescript

I want to use an Applescript to set my Mac screen resolution to "Scaled", "Larger text".

I found the stackoverflow script below which works great to select the 2nd scaled resolution button. However, I would like to select the 1st, "Larger text". That resolution requires an OK button click which I don't know how to do.

```
tell application "System Preferences"
    reveal anchor "displaysDisplayTab" of pane 
               "com.apple.preference.displays"
end tell
tell application "System Events" to tell process "System Preferences" to tell window "Built-in Retina Display"
    click radio button "Scaled" of radio group 1 of tab group 1
    click radio button 2 of radio group 1 of group 1 of tab group 1
end tell
quit application "System Preferences"
```

I changed button 2 to button 1, but there was no change in the resolution.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a command line util called [displayplacer](https://github.com/jakehilborn/displayplacer) that makes this super easy - especially for multi-monitor setups. For example, I can set my MacBook Pro to *Larger Text* by executing `displayplacer "id:F466F621-B5FA-04A0-0800-CFA6C258DECD res:1024x640 scaling:on origin:(-1024,1060) degree:0"`

Also available via Homebrew: `brew tap jakehilborn/jakehilborn && brew install displayplacer`

Answer (score 0):

This AppleScript code works for me using the latest version of macOS Mojave.

```
tell application "System Events" to tell process "System Preferences" to tell window "Built-in Retina Display"
    click radio button "Scaled" of radio group 1 of tab group 1
    click radio button 1 of radio group 1 of group 2 of tab group 1
    delay 0.1 -- May Need To Adjust
    try
        click button "OK" of sheet 1
    end try
end tell
quit application "System Preferences"
```

Comment: Thanks wch1zpink for your help. I got an error message with your script. However, when I added your click button "OK" code to my original script, it worked fine. So, I now have a working script.